# Regular Expression in C# for Last Name that includes internal space

Tags: c#, regex, spaces

I'd like a Regular Expression for C# that matches "Johnson", "Del Sol", or "Del La Range"; in other words, it should match words with spaces in the middle but no space at the start or at the end.

Comment: What does the input string look like?  Is the last name the only part of the string, or is it a sentence, or possibly a full name with optionally more spaces?  I think context is important here.

Answer (score 5):

```
^\p{L}+(\s+\p{L}+)*$
```

This regex has the following features:

- Will match a one letter last name (e.g. Malcolm X's last name)
- Will not match last names containing numbers (like anything with a `\w` or a `[^ ]` will)
- Matches unicode letters

But what about last names like "O'Connor" or hyphenated last names ... hmm ...

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

**Edit:** Here's a slight improvement that allows one-latter names and hyphens/apostrophes in the name:

```
^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z'- ]*[a-zA-Z']?$
```

Comment: Malcolm X would not be happy about this... (requiring minimum of 2 letter last names that is...)

Comment: The shortest REAL name I can think of is "Ng."  Should be fine. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that upon review, but didn't bother changing because I didn't consider a one-letter last name... Post is edited now anyway with a few other improvements.

Comment: +1 for tackling ' and -.  (I don't know if the first character needs to accept an apostrophe though... or if a-- should be a valid last name)

Comment: @Daniel: Cheers. And yeah, it *probably* doesn't need to accept ' as the first char, but can't hurt. Note that it shouldn't accept a hyphen as the last char, so a-b would be valid but not a-- (unless one of my quantifiers is wrong).

Comment: How would I change this to only allow single spaces inside the name, not more than one space?

Comment: I take it you mean not more than one space in a row? Try the following (it may not quite work, as I haven't tested): ^[a-zA-Z'](([a-zA-Z])+['- ]?)*[a-zA-Z']?$

Answer (score 3):

In the name "Ṣalāḥ ad-Dīn Yūsuf ibn Ayyūb" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saladdin), which is the first name, and which is the last? What about in the name "Roberto Garcia y Vega" (invented)? "Chiang Kai-shek" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_Kai-shek)?

Spaces in names are the least of your problems! See [Personal names in a global application: What to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620118/personal-names-in-a-global-application-what-to-store).

Comment: I agree. No matter how hard you try you will always find names that don't match correctly. I mean, if you don't have complete control on what names you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The ? qualifier is your friend.  Makes a shortest-possible match instead of a greedy one.  Use it for the first name,  as in:

```
^(.+?) (.+)$
```

Group 1 grabs everything up to the first space, group 2 gets the rest.

Of course, now what do you do if the *first* name contains spaces?

Comment: Nice and simple, but I think it will match "238 39592" as well, which aren't words.

Comment: then replace "." with "\w" or "[a-zA-Z]"

Comment: Not sure if the OP wants to match the last name by itself or within a string containing both the first and last names... I supposed the former, while you seem to have done the latter. Still, it appears your regex allows spaces at the start or end, which needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
^[^\s][\w\s]*[^\s]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/
```

Allows standard punctuation and spaces, but cannot start with punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is more what you were looking for:

```
^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$
```

This should match the beginning of the line with no space, alpha characters or a space, and no space at the end.

This works in irb, but last time I worked with C#, I've used similar regexes:

(zero is good, nil means failed)

```
>> "Di Giorno" =~ /^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$/
=> 0
>> "DiGiorno" =~ /^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$/
=> 0
>> " DiGiorno" =~ /^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$/
=> nil
>> "DiGiorno " =~ /^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$/
=> nil
>> "Di Gior no" =~ /^[^ ][a-zA-Z ]+[^ ]$/
=> 0
```

Comment: Using the [^ ] will match last names starting or ending with numbers, punctuation, etc...

Comment: Danny's right.  I responded with the same solution and retracted it when I realized this.