# Display Full Name in ASP.NET LoginName control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page using a login control with custom authentication.  I was wondering if it's possible to have a "Welcome [FirstName] [LastName]" message using the LoginName control instead of the [UserName] that is accessed by default.

I'm thinking of storing these info in the Session object if it's not possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to override the `RenderContents` method or make your own LoginName control. Something like this will do the trick:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Profile.FullName))
            return;

      nameToDisplay = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Profile.FullName);
      string formatExpression = this.FormatString;
      if (formatExpression .Length == 0)
      {
            writer.Write(nameToDisplay);
      }
      else
      {
            try
            {
                  writer.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, formatExpression, new object[1] { nameToDisplay });
            }
            catch (FormatException exception)
            {
                  throw new FormatException("Invalid FormatString", exception1);
            }
      }
}
```

Also, see here for a brief article on [working with LoginName](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/10/25/libertyonwhidbey.html).

Comment: I'm not using the default ASP.NET providers and not using Profile also. I settled with storing the user's full name in the session object instead. Thanks!

Comment: link is in a diferent page.

Answer (score 2):

create a LoginName control in redirect page it may be Masterpage.aspx or any other page.

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
```

then insert these line of code inside the page_load in .cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this can come from anywhere like session, database
    string fullName = "ABC XYZ";
    LoginName1.FormatString = "welcome" + " - " + fullName ; //output: welcome - ABC XYZ

    or

    LoginName1.FormatString = fullName; // output: ABC XYZ
}
```

is this helpful for you???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see [Personal names in a global application: What to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620118/personal-names-in-a-global-application-what-to-store). Even if your site is limited to the US, I'm pretty sure I've seen some foreigners around here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.formatstring.aspx) property to set the welcome message to any string you want. When combined with expression builders (e.g. [<%$ expressionPrefix: expressionValue %>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)) you would have a flexible way to define output.